# Python Marking Error?

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python. In school we have to create a maths game, and I am creating a 9 times table game. However, it tells me the answer is incorrect even if it is correct? please help!

```
import random
print(" Hello there!")#prints hello there
print("What is your name?")#asks user for a name
name= input()#sets name to the input
print(name, ", are you ready to test your nine times table? ")#asks user if they are ready to test their 9 times table
print (name, ", here we go!")#prints here we go
print ("Question 1:")#prints Question 1:
number1 = random.randint(1,12)#sets number1 to a random value from 1 to 12
answer= 9*number1#sets answer to 9 times number1
print ("what is 9 times", number1, "?")#asks what is 9 times number 1
if answer==input():
    print ("well done," , name,"thats correct!")
else:
    print("sorry, the correct answer was", answer, )
```

Comment: If you are using Python 3 (seems like it), this `if answer==input():` is comparing strings with numbers.

Comment: `print(" Hello there!")#prints hello there` Don't do this! Comments are for explaining what is not obvious about a program, not for reading it aloud. This kind of noise only makes your code *harder* to read and work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are comparing a string (`input()`) to a number (`answer`).

You can fix this by doing:

```
if answer==int(input()):
```

This converts your `input()` to an [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). As a benefit, it will also throw an error if the user puts in something other than an `int`.

This assumes that you'll continue to do integer multiplication. If not, you may want to look at [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)

Comment: similarly you could cast `answer` to a `str`, that way if the user entered a non-number it would just be considered not equal instead of raising an error.

Comment: While true, since this is a mathematical test, it makes more sense to get that type of error. At least to me. You could then give error messages such as "please enter a number" instead of just "that is not equal".

Comment: I agree, although with the `input()` imbedded in the condition and the possibility that the OP is not familiar with `try:except:` I thought it was a valid point to add.